Cyclodextrins: Why is the WHOLE exterior hydrophilic?
I get why the upper and lower "openings" of the molecule are hydrophilic (because of the hydroxy groups), but in all the figures I have seen, it is always the WHOLE exterior that is shown as hydrophilic, not just the upper and lower part (see blue part in screenshots below).
I just do not see why the central part of the exterior should also be hydrophilic. The oxygen atoms in the center can not be the reason in my opinion, since they do not really contribute to any significant polarity. In fact, if they did, then this would also mean that the interior would be hydrophilic as well, not just the outside?
Below, you can see one of the figures that shows the whole exterior in blue (meaning hydrophilic) vs. the way I would have dyed it.
Hope you can help me with this! :)



"Hydrophilicity" and "hydrophobicity" (or "lipophilicity") are not absolutes, but relative qualities.
To quote Wikipedia,

[T]he interior of the toroid [hollow space, hohlraum] is considerably less hydrophilic than
the aqueous environment and thus able to host hydrophobic molecules.
In contrast, the exterior is sufficiently hydrophilic to impart [to]
cyclodextrins... water solubility.

I.E., there are more hydroxyl groups exposed along the edges of the hollow truncated cone (my wording, rather than toroid) than the interior, making the edges, and thereby the exterior more hydrophilic.

It is also worth noting that the solubilities of only cyclodextrins (not necessarily HG inclusions) change with glucose units, due to the completeness of hydrogen bonding between these external rims, water molecules inside the cavity, and water molecules of the solution. For example, α-cyclodextrin and γ-cyclodextrin are approximately 8x and 13x more soluble than β-cyclodextrin, because the hydrogen bonding between β-CD and water molecules of solution is less complete than in the other two.

Thanks for your answer, but I have to ask again (sorry if you think you have already adressed that):
Why is the whole exterior hydrophilic and not only the edges, where the hydroxyl groups are?

@Theiserino Acetal groups are also hydrophilic.

@DrMoishe Pippik Ah wait, maybe I understood it now: Per Glucose unit, there are 2 hydroxy groups pointing outwards (C3 and C6) and only one pointing inwards (C2), so netto the outside is more hydrophilic than the inside? I still am surprised that the C2 hydroxy group doesnt make the interior more hydrophilic, but it makes a bit more sense now. Am I thinking correctly here?

@Theiserino No, there are no hydroxyl groups pointing inwards. The C2 and C3 hydroxyl groups comprise the narrow ring of the pointed cylinder. The C6 hydroxyl groups comprise the wider ring of the pointed cylinder. Both are exocyclic from the internal cavity. It is the hydrogen bonding of water molecules to the hydroxyl groups on both narrow and wide rings that affords the water-solubility of the CD, and the lack of hydrogen bonding within the cavity that makes the inside hydrophobic. (All relative terms, of course.)

@Sonder Thanks for the explanation, though the wider ring is comprised by the C2 and C3, not the C6, as far as I know. I would like to ask you if you could give me a link which I can use to see where your statement about the exocyclic C3 and C2 comes from. Most 3D animations of cyclodextrins I have seen today show that the C2, while not pointing inwards, is also not pointing outwards, its just equatorial and thus aligned with the ring "plane". I think this would also make perfekt sense to explain why the exterior is hydrophilic and the interior hydrophobic. Best regards! :)

@Theiserino You have my deepest apologies. I meant to comment that the C6 groups comprise the narrower ring, not C2/C3. However, the point remains that all hydroxyl groups are exocyclic. For reference, see this image, or check out Atwood and Steed's excellent book on supramolecular chemistry (section 6.3.1). Alternatively, a paper on cyclodextrin structure.

@Sonder Thanks so much, I will definitely read it!
